# Update action in x business hours

Tags: businesshours

I have a requirement where I need to send email in 8 business hours. It should respect holidays and weekends.

Example: Office Hours 8 AM to 5 PM

If case is created at 4 PM Friday then email must be sent to 3 PM on Monday as Saturday Sunday are non working days.

Should I write trigger and Schedule action or Create field and update value and use WF rule. Sample code will be helpful.

Thanks in Advanced!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write a Case Trigger and call a trigger handler. Add this following method to return DateTime respecting business hours.

```
public static DateTime SLADateTime(Datetime input, Long intervalMilliseconds)
    {
         BusinessHours defaultBH = [SELECT Id FROM BusinessHours WHERE IsDefault = true];
         return BusinessHours.add(defaultBH.Id, input, intervalMilliseconds);
    }
```

You need to pass the creation datetime and 8*60*60*1000 as duration, considering 8 hours is the duration.

Create a new datetime field and store the above returned value in that field.

Finally create a scheduled action through workflow or process builder based on this datetime and send an email.

Comment: Hi Santanu, Thanks for your response . This is really helpful.

Comment: Hi Santanu, Will it follow Current user time zone?  I set Business Hours as 8 AM to 5 PM EST.

Comment: It will follow any timezone which has been defined in business hours configuration.